# Condition on Laravel Form Request Validation

Tags: validation, laravel-8, laravel-formrequest

I am new to Laravel. I am making validation through form requests. But I want to set a condition that if the check vendor exists return true then rules needs to be checked otherwise not.  I'm making API so I want a JSON response in the else section. For that what should I write in the else section because I have tried many ways(Using Trait, authorization function) but gives an error?

```
      $check_vendor_exists = Vendor::where('user_id', Auth::id())->get()->toArray();
      if (empty($check_vendor_exists)) {
          return [
              'business_name' => 'required||regex:/^[a-zA-Z_ ]*$/|max:191',
              'business_id' => 'required|exists:businesses,id',
              'business_email' => 'required|email|max:191|unique:vendors,business_email,NULL,id,deleted_at,NULL',
              'country_id' => 'nullable|exists:countries,id',
              'state_id' => 'nullable|exists:states,id',
              'city_id' => 'nullable|exists:cities,id',
              'business_logo' => 'nullable|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg|max:5120',
              'opening_hours' =>  'nullable|json',
              'gst_no' => 'required||regex:/^[0-9]{2}[A-Z]{5}[0-9]{4}[A-Z]{1}[1-9A-Z]{1}Z[0-9A-Z]{1}$/|max:191',
          ];
      } else {
          return $this->getMessages([], config('constants.messages.errors.something_wrong'), config('constants.validation_codes.unprocessable_entity'), false);
      }
```

Comment: I'm confused. Do you want to return some response in json format for you API endpoint?

Comment: Yes, I want JSON response. and getmessage is trait that I have made but when I'm using it, it throws an error.

Comment: Ok. You can check @Hermerson Varela answer. You can return any response in JSON that way.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand your question, If you're working on an API and you just need to return `true`

You can use the response object in the else statement:

```
return response()->json(['message' => true]);
```

or

```
return response()->json(true);
```